# Kendo Grid Export to Excel error on large dataset

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, serialization, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am getting the below error when trying to export to Excel from a Kendo grid of large data.  It's working fine when we have small data on grid.

> Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON  JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property

```
.Excel(excel => excel
    .FileName("Trip List Export.xlsx")
    .Filterable(false)
    .ProxyURL(Url.Action("ExcelExport", "Grid"))
    .AllPages(true)
)

public ActionResult ExcelExport(string contentType, string base64, string fileName)
{
    var fileContents = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    return File(fileContents, contentType, fileName);
}
```

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the problem is: *The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property*. What is your question?

Comment: how to resolve this problem, I already set the maxjsonlength property in web.config

Comment: <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength = "2147483647"></jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>

Comment: So apparently your *huge data on grid* is larger than that size. Again, what is your question?

Comment: this is the max length which I already set in web.config, So what it the solutions to resolve that issue, its working fine when grid have small data.

Comment: The solution is to export less data than the max length, as I said before. ***So apparently your huge data on grid is larger than that size.*** It's working fine with small data because that small data is less than that max. I'm not sure why you're having difficulty understanding this issue. **You have a container that will hold a maximum amount. That container is fine as long as what you put into it is less than that amount. If you try to put too much, it doesn't work because the container is not large enough, and you have no larger container to use.*

Comment: @Piush - the solution is to break the export into manageable amounts of data.  Alternatively,  per Telerik you can use server-side processing using RadSpreadStreamProcessing (https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/excel-export).  I have not used this component.

Comment: @bednarjm. yes agree with your comment. working on to make export to excel server side.

Comment: @KenWhite Here i am looking for solutions, I already explaied the things, instaed of providing solutons you are just making the issue

Comment: Use server side streaming to push large amounts of data as an excel file via browser download.  Should there be caution on pushing 2GB+ Excel content? As in why does the user need that much data in Excel and are there other better resource allocations tools/solutions for the downstream analysis/report generation they want

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "Excel" part and add this

```
.ToolBar(toolBar => { toolBar.Custom().Text("Export To Excel")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "export" })
            .Url(Url.Action("ExcelExport", "Grid")); })
```

then , in controller:

```
    public ActionResult ExcelExport([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request 
    { 

        var workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

        //Create new Excel sheet
        var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet();

        //(Optional) set the width of the columns
        sheet.SetColumnWidth(0, 10 * 256);
        sheet.SetColumnWidth(1, 50 * 256);
        sheet.SetColumnWidth(2, 50 * 256);
        sheet.SetColumnWidth(3, 50 * 256);

        //Create a header row
        var headerRow = sheet.CreateRow(0);

        //Set the column names in the header row
        headerRow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Product ID");
        headerRow.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("Product Name");
        headerRow.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("Unit Price");
        headerRow.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue("Quantity Per Unit");

        //(Optional) freeze the header row so it is not scrolled
        sheet.CreateFreezePane(0, 1, 0, 1);
        var models = _priceRepository.Get().ToDataSourceResult(request).Data;
        int rowNumber = 1;

        //Populate the sheet with values from the grid data
        foreach (RentPriceModel model in models)
        {
            //Create a new row
            var row = sheet.CreateRow(rowNumber++);

            //Set values for the cells
            row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(model.Id);
            row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue(model.Branch.Name);
            row.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue(model.CarClass.Name);
            row.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue(model.Interval);
        }

        //Write the workbook to a memory stream
        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
        workbook.Write(output);

        //Return the result to the end user

        return File(output.ToArray(),   //The binary data of the XLS file
            "application/vnd.ms-excel", //MIME type of Excel files
            "GridExcelExport.xls");
    }`
```

Note that I use my custom models and also [this library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/)

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps. That way I solved the problem

```
public virtual ActionResult Index_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, bool isActive)
        {
            return new LargeJsonResult { Data = getAssets(isActive).ToDataSourceResult(request), MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue };

        }

public class LargeJsonResult : JsonResult
{
    public int MaxJsonLength { get; set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType))
        {
            response.ContentType = ContentType;
        }
        else
        {
            response.ContentType = "application/json";
        }

        if (ContentEncoding != null)
        {
            response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;
        }

        if (Data != null)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            if (MaxJsonLength.HasValue)
            {
                serializer.MaxJsonLength = MaxJsonLength.Value;
            }
            response.Write(serializer.Serialize(Data));
        }
    }
}
```